# How Can I Display my Questionnaire and decide what to do based on that Android App

Tags: java, android

I am working on an App in Android Studios and what I want it to do is it should ask the user would you like to either to listen to Music or watch Videos after they decide what mood they are in. The problem is that when I click the mood it goes straight to the video and when I click the back button it then asks if they would like to music or videos. So it needs to be the other way around. I am working on this in Android Studios. I will paste the code down below.

This is the code for the `MainActivity.java`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HappyButton);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SadButton);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MellowButton);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MotivatedButton);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AngryButton);


    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,theOptionsPage.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            openHappy();
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        openSad();

        }


    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMello();
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            openMotivated();
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            openAngry();
        }
    });


}

    public void showMe(View v){
       String button_text;
       button_text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
       if(button_text.equals("HAPPY")){
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,theOptionsPage.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    }



                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

        }

        public void openHappy(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,YoutubeHappy.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void openSad(){
            Intent sadintent = new Intent(this,YoutubeSad.class);
            startActivity(sadintent);
        }

        public void openMello(){
            Intent mellowintent = new Intent(this,YoutubeMellow.class);
            startActivity(mellowintent);

        }
        public void openMotivated(){
            Intent motivatedintent = new Intent(this,YoutubeMotivated.class);
            startActivity(motivatedintent);
        }
        public void openAngry(){
            Intent angryintent = new Intent(this,YoutubeAngry.class);{
                startActivity(angryintent);
            }
        }




    }
```

This is the `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.code.mohamedali.hackathon2018.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/HappyButton"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="HAPPY"
    android:onClick="showMe"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/FeelingView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SadButton"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="SAD"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/HappyButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/AngryButton"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="ANGRY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SadButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/MotivatedButton"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="MOTIVATED"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AngryButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/MellowButton"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="MELLOW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MotivatedButton" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FeelingView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="How Are You Feeling Today?"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the `OptionsPage` `Code` and `XML`

```
public class theOptionsPage extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options_page);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MusicButton);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.VideoButton);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

 //             Intent in1 = new Intent( MainActivity.this , theOptionsPage.class);
//                startActivity(in1);

        }
    });



}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Would You Like Muisc or Videos"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.172" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/MusicButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:text="Music"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/VideoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
    android:text="Videos"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/MusicButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you see your code in button0 click event:

```
button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,theOptionsPage.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            openHappy();
        }
    });
```

See that after starting the theOptionsPage activty, immediately u call openHappy(); This is why it starts the "theOptionPage" and then immediately starts the "YoutubeHappy" activity.

So remove the openHappy() call inside the click listener and then start the activity from "theOptionPage"

Comment: I will also post the `OptionsPage` so you can get a better view

Comment: Tell me onething, why are you calling openHappy() immediately after starting the "theOptionsPage" ?

Comment: I was playing around with it trying to get it to show the Options for either music or videos and then to display the videos if the person selected video or music if they selected music.

Comment: Can you please remove openHappy() and try. Check what happens

Comment: I did it shows the menu asking if they want to listen to music or watch a video. Now I want it so when they click video they see the youtube video which I already have pop or if they click image then it will be image of my choosing.

Comment: post the code of options page and the xml. Also you told it displays a menu so without the code its difficult to understand.

Comment: I posted it above

Comment: Yes now inside 
        
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,YoutubeHappy.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });         

Basically all the methods you have in mainactivity like openHappy() should be in your optionsPage. Isn't this what you are looking for